# How come the Beast allows Belle to ride off through the woods ridden with wolves to rescue her father?

Tags: plot-explanation, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In the movie *Beauty and the Beast*, the path between the village and the cursed castle is ridden with blood-thirsty wolves who pound upon whoever passes through.

This happened multiple times e.g. when Belle's father first crossed the forest into the path leading him to the castle unknowingly or when Belle used Phillippe (the horse) to reach his father who was imprisoned by the Beast.

There was also this one time when the Beast came to the rescue of Belle as she was attacked by these wolves and got injured himself.

However, when Belle's father is seen to be in danger, the Beast asks Belle to go rescue him and she goes off on a horse through the same path.

**How come the Beast never thought of the blood-thirsty wolves waiting on the same path when Belle passed through it?**

This has baffled me ever since I saw the movie.

I hope someone knows why this was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wolves are no longer a threat after their confrontation with Belle and the Beast. Hurt and injured by a stronger opponent, they ran away and likely wouldn't attack again.